# Sharing data along controllers and memory fatal error

Tags: php, pdo, controller

I have like 3 shared controllers. SharedAdsController, SharedUserController and a SharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController.

If i want to use them across eachother i get a allowed memory size. Changing memory limit IS NOT AN OPTION.

SharedUserController:

```
class clsSharedUserController{  
    // controller
    protected $o_clsSharedAdsController;        
    protected $o_clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController;        

    // construct
    public function __construct($smarty, $db) {             
        if (is_object($smarty)) {
            $this->o_smarty = $smarty;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Smarty not set!");
        }       

        if (is_object($db)) {
            $this->db = $db;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("db not set!");
        }

        // controller
        $this->o_clsSharedAdsController = new clsSharedAdsController($this->o_smarty, $this->db);
        $this->o_clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController = new clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController($this->o_smarty, $this->db);
    }
}
```

SharedAdsController:

```
class clsSharedAdsController{
    // controller
    protected $o_clsSharedUserController;   
    protected $o_clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController;    

    // construct
    public function __construct($smarty, $db) {             
        if (is_object($smarty)) {
            $this->o_smarty = $smarty;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Smarty not set!");
        }       

        if (is_object($db)) {
            $this->db = $db;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("db not set!");
        }

        // controller
        $this->o_clsSharedUserController = new clsSharedUserController($this->o_smarty, $this->db);
        $this->o_clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController = new clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController($this->o_smarty, $this->db);
    }
}
```

SharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController

```
class clsSharedCategoriesAndPropertiesController{
    // db
    protected $o_clsDBCategoriesAndProperties;

    // construct
    public function __construct($smarty, $db) {             
        if (is_object($smarty)) {
            $this->o_smarty = $smarty;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Smarty not set!");
        }       

        if (is_object($db)) {
            $this->db = $db;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("db not set!");
        }

        $this->o_clsDBCategoriesAndProperties = new clsDBCategoriesAndProperties($this->db);
    }
```

As you can see sharedUsercontroller is making a new sharedadscontroller, sharedadscontroller is making a new sharedusercontroller. I think this is turning into a loop. How can i fix this? I mean i can simply remove the line that creates a new controller, but i need data from that other controller. Can i check somehow if the controllers exists or should i do it in an other way? If so, how?

Comment: check for php directives max input, max execution time, post max size etc...

Comment: `max_input_time = 30`, `max_execution_time = 30`, `post_max_size = 64M`. But i feel like there is something wrong in my code, that is causing this. Not the memory limit of the server.

Comment: Also changing memory_limit is not a real option, because i definately think there is something wrong in my code, nothing to do with memory

Comment: max_input_time = 3000, max_execution_time = 3000, post_max_size = 1024M also set memory limit to no-limit

Comment: HOw many records you are fetching?

Comment: Then i get Out of memory. I am not fetching that much, mostly 10 records

Comment: If you fetching 10 records then check your code, might be getting into infinite loop

Comment: Wrong analyses can you please review my topic?

Comment: There is an infinite loop in the constructors of `clsSharedAdsController` and `clsSharedUserController`. In `clsSharedAdsController` you instantiate a new instance of the `clsSharedUserController` which in it's constructor instantiates a new instance of the `clsSharedAdsController` which then goes on to instantiate a new instance of the `clsSharedUserController` which goes on in an infinite loop until php runs out of memory.

Comment: I know that, because that's what i said in my topic. How do i fix it?